# Rename wordpress theme name Twenty Twelve

Tags: wordpress, themes, rename, dashboard

Sorry if my tune is not good!

I want to change the name of wordpress theme "Twenty Twelve" to "iBlast".

**Problem:**

When I rename it from "**Wordpress->wp-content->theme->Twenty Twelve**" directory.
It display in dashboard as "Twenty Twelve/iBlast".
But it should display just "iBlast", not "Twenty Twelve/iBlast".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ayodele Ayoola said it...you can also create [child themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), this may be a better option for you.

also themes may update themselves, wiping out your hard work, check [this post out](http://www.davidjrush.com/blog/2012/09/renaming-your-wordpress-theme/) or [this one](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/wordpress-child-themes-dev/)

good luck and happy learning curves ;)

Answer (score 0):

To change it you'll need to edit the style.css file in the base directory of the theme.